# Magento 2: Load a field based on another field in admin configuration

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.0.

Here I need to load **Attribute Type multi-select** based on the option we choose in Document Type.
[image]

Is that possible by writing jQuery change events? If so, Where to add my js code to reflect here?

Comment: Have you used UI Components fields?

Comment: Nope. I have mentioned this in system.xml since it is coming in Stores->Configuration page.

Comment: I have just designed those fields in the frontend source model which we give in system.xml.

Comment: @Octopus Hello Mate, Did you find a solution for this? I am also trying to achieve the same. If you have a solution, please guide

Comment: @Siv Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using js and placed it under `view->adminhtml->web->js->dropdownValidation.js`. You have to mention this js in the 'adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml' under `vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml`.

Here is the code I am having

```
require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
            $("[id*=_upload_docType]").trigger('click');
        });
    
        $("tr#row_ls_id_idUpload_fieldOptionsToUpload td.value td.col-actions-add button").click(function () {
            $("[id*=_upload_docType]").trigger('click');
        });
    
        var idUpload = function (event) {
    
            var currentTarget = event.target;
            var currentId = currentTarget.id;
    
            if (currentId) {
                var currentTargetValue = currentTarget.value;
                var splittedId = (currentId).split("_upload_")[1];
                var docType = "docType";
                var attrType = "attrType";
    
                if (splittedId == docType) {
                    var optionValues = currentTarget.parentElement.next().firstChild;
                    var optionLength = optionValues.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < optionLength; i++) {
                        var checkPrefix = optionValues[i].value.split(currentTargetValue)[0];
                        if (checkPrefix != "" || checkPrefix == null) {
                            optionValues[i].hide();
                        } else {
                            optionValues[i].show();
                        }
                    }
                    if (event.type == "change" || currentTargetValue == 0) {
                        $(optionValues).val('0');
                    }
                }
    
                if (splittedId == attrType) {
                    var attrOptionsValue = currentTarget.parentElement.previous().children[0].value;
                    if (attrOptionsValue == "0") {
                        var attrValues = currentTarget;
                        var attrLength = attrValues.length;
                        for (i = 0; i < attrLength; i++) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                currentTarget[0].show();
                            } else {
                                currentTarget[i].hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $("[id*=_upload_docType]").trigger('click');
            }
        };
    
        $('#ls_id_idUpload').change(idUpload);
        $('#ls_id_idUpload').click(idUpload);
    });
```